# Can you call a function from a function's parameter?

Tags: javascript

This is my code, and I want to use `.forEach` to execute the functions in the array.

```
const ar = new Array ('function1', 'function2', 'function3', 'function4');
ar.forEach(element => element();)
```

However, when I run this code, it gives me `Uncaught Typerror: element is not a function.`
I have tried

```
ar.forEach(element => {element = var x; x();})
```

But, it only gives me the error `Uncaught Typerror: x is not a function.`
If you can help, thanks!

Comment: Instead of having Strings in your Array, can't you store functions directly? `[function1, function2...]` Otherwise, if you require Strings to be passed, you would need to use their scope to access them from their name. For example, if they're in the global scope, you would do: `arr.forEach(x => window[x]());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by just adding the actual functions to the array:

```js
const f1 = () => console.log('f1');
const f2 = () => console.log('f2');
const f3 = () => console.log('f3');
const f4 = () => console.log('f4');
const functions = [f1, f2, f3, f4];

functions.forEach(f => f());
```

Or creating an object that maps the keys in your array to the actual functions you want to call:

```js
const f1 = () => console.log('f1');
const f2 = () => console.log('f2');
const f3 = () => console.log('f3');
const f4 = () => console.log('f4');
const functions = { f1, f2, f3, f4 };
const functionKeys = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'];

functionKeys.forEach(key => functions[key]());
```

This also applies if your functions live in the global scope:

```js
window.f1 = () => console.log('f1');
window.f2 = () => console.log('f2');
window.f3 = () => console.log('f3');
window.f4 = () => console.log('f4');

const functionKeys = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'];

functionKeys.forEach(key => window[key]());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this but your array would have to consist of functions not strings

e.g.:

```js
const functions = [ () => console.log('Hi'), () => console.log('Hello world') ];

functions.forEach(f => f());
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. But instead of having Strings inside your Array as in your case here, you need to have the functions themselves

```
const ar = new Array (
    () => {console.log('function1')},
    () => {console.log('function2')},
    () => {console.log('function3')},
    () => {console.log('function4')}
);
    
ar.forEach(element => element();)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing something wrong! if you want to put your functions inside an array and then call them in a forEach, it should work normally.
try this:

```
const f1 = ()=> console.log("f1");
const f2 = ()=> console.log("f2");
const ar = new Array(f1, f2);
ar.forEach((f)=> f())
// output: 
// f1
// f2
```